# PhoneGap application not working on Google Ripple

Tags: jquery, cordova, ripple

I'm developing a phoneGap application. When I test my application in the browser there is no problem. Everythings works well. But when I am try it in ripple, my javascript does not work. 
In detail: The user can login the system and if it successfully redirects to another page (used jquery mobile) it works well in chrome, internet explorer, and firefox. But does not work in ripple.
My code is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css">

    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var credentials = 'admin:adminabc';
            var authType = "Basic " + credentials;
            $('#loginForm').submit(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type : "GET",
                    url :  'http://localhost:30673/api/user/Get',
                    data : 'json',
                    beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                         xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authType);
                    },
                    success : function(data, textStatus) {
                        $.mobile.changePage("#menu", {
                            transition : "slideup"
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

            $("#aboutUs").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type : "GET",
                    url :  'http://localhost:30673/api/AboutMeWA/',
                    data : 'json',
                    beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                         xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authType);
                    },
                    success : function(data, textStatus) {
                        $('#aboutMeTitle').val(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        function onBodyLoad() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            function onDeviceReady() {
                document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
                document.addEventListener("resume", onResume,  false);
            }

            function onPause() {
                alert("paused");
            }

            function onResume() {
                alert("resume");
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
    <div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" >
            <h4> Ziro </h4>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <form id="loginForm">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="textinput1"> Kullanıcı Adı:     </label>
                    <input name="" id="userName"  placeholder="username" value="" type="text">
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="textinput2"> Password</label>
                    <input name="" id="password"  placeholder="password" value="" type="password">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" data-theme="a" data- icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="left"
                value="Login">
            </form>
            <a href="#menu" class="ui-link" data- transition="flip">Menü</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a"  data-position="fixed">
            <h3> FF Yazılım </h3>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="menu" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Geri">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" >
            <h4> Ziro Mobilya </h4>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="a" data- inset="true">
                <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
                    Panel
                </li>
                <li data-theme="c">
                    <a href="#about" data-transition="flip"  id="aboutUs"> Hakkımızda </a>
                </li>
                <li data-theme="c">
                    <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">  Referans Resimleri </a>
                </li>
                <li data-theme="c">
                    <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide"> Servis Resimleri </a>
                </li>
                <li data-theme="c">
                    <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide"> Slogan </a>
                </li>
                <li data-theme="c">
                    <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide"> İstatistikler </a>
                </li>
                <li data-theme="c">
                    <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">  Button </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a"  data-position="fixed">
            <h3> FF Yazılım </h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="about" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Geri">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3> Hakkımızda </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div style="">
                <img style="width: 288px; height: 100px"  src="http://aknera.com/temp/default/images/background3.jpg">
            </div>
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="a" href="#page1" data-icon="arrow-l"
            data-iconpos="left"> Galeriden Resim Seç </a>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="textinput2"> Başlık: </label>
                <input name="" id="aboutMeTitle" placeholder=""  value="" type="text" data-mini="true">
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="textarea2"> Açıklama </label>
                <textarea name="" id="textarea2" placeholder=""  data-mini="true"></textarea>                                                           




            </div>
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="a" href="#page1" data-icon="alert" data-iconpos="left"> Kaydet </a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a"  data-position="fixed">
            <h3> FF Yazılım </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
 </html>
```

My application structure is shown below:

[image]

Error code is:xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//localhost%3A30673/ap‌​i/user/Get%3Fjson rippleapi.herokuapp.com Status Code:500 Internal Server Error I'am getting data from my localhost post adress:localhost:30673/api/user/Get'; It is working well in browser . And getting data from localhost:30673/api/user/Get. But in ripple it tries to get data from There: xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//localhost%3A30673/api/u‌​ser/Get%3Fjson rippleapi.herokuapp.com

Need advice guys.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Error code is:xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//localhost%3A30673/api/user/Get%3Fjson
rippleapi.herokuapp.com 

Status Code:500
Internal Server Error

I'am getting data from my localhost post adress:http://localhost:30673/api/user/Get'

It is working well in browser . And getting data from http://localhost:30673/api/user/Get.

But in ripple it tries to get data from There:

xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//localhost%3A30673/api/user/Get%3Fjson
rippleapi.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The issue that you are likely running into is that you are using Ripple's cross-domain proxy which is turned on in settings by default.

The cross-domain-proxy has 3 settings: "remote", "local" and "disabled".
In my situation I actually had to disable it, but in some cases you would be able to use "local".

Possible scenarios:

1) *your local application calls a remote service somewhere on another server:*

you would either use "remote" or "disabled" depending on the configuration on the remote server.

2) *your local application is on "localhost" and you are making a call to another localhost accessible URL:*

you would either use "local" or "disabled" depending on your cross domain settings and such.

3) *you are running a local app that calls a server that is also local but in a vm or something that makes it inaccessible to a proxy on "localhost":*

you need to have it set to "disabled", and make sure your api server has settings to allow cross-domain requests. Most notably you would want to set the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header.

Comment: AFAIK for (1)  scenario one can also use "local". Using local proxy is a standard approach for handling Cross-Domain Ajax

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. It was happening when I was trying to connect to my WebAPI service hosted on **IISExpress**.

After I changed hosting to my **local IIS** server, the error dissapeared and I was able to connect to my WebAPI service using Ripple. Of course, you will have to change url pointing to your service (in your case it is `http://localhost:30673`).