# Cannot Make AJAX Call in Google Ripple PhoneGap Emulation (500 Error)

Tags: ajax, json, google-chrome, cordova, ripple

I'd add a comment here:

[PhoneGap application not working on Google Ripple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402422/phonegap-application-not-working-on-google-ripple)

but given my low reputation on StackOverflow (as elsewhere), I can't. That thread raises similar issues but does not answer my question. I am trying to test the functionality of an HTML5 page that will eventually be made into a mobile app with PhoneGap. The page makes an AJAX call to a JSON service via jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'latest.json',
            type: 'get',
            datatype: 'json',
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
            //…make it so
    });
});
```

and runs flawlessly as HTML5 in Chrome. However, when using the Ripple PhoneGap emulation available for Chrome, the JSON fails with a 500 error:

> GET https://rippleapi.herokuapp.com/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=latest.json 500 (Internal Server Error) rippleapi.herokuapp.com/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=latest.json:1

The suggested answer to the question linked above reads:

> I had the same issue. It was happening when I was trying to connect to my WebAPI service hosted on IISExpress.
>
> After I changed hosting to my local IIS server, the error dissapeared (sic) and I was able to connect to my WebAPI service using Ripple.

But I'm not running IIS or indeed anything locally -- it's all running off a remote server hosted by an ISP. Since, as I say, this page runs fine in non-emulation mode, the fault would appear to be in Ripple. Any help making this emulation operate correctly will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I added an answer to the question that you referenced above. You may want to check and see if it also answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/21742515/530984

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: serviceurl + "/GetBusinessPartner/",
         dataType: "json",
         crossDomain: true,
         success: function (responseData) {
         },
         error: function (xhr) {
         }
   });
```

This worked for me and in ripple setting disable cross domain proxy.