# Cordova for Visual Studio 2015 Preview: not able to request content from a remote host

Tags: jquery, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

I was working with cordova for visual studio 2013 without any problems. Today i installed VS2015 preview and tried to port my project but got stuck with a simple web request.

So i created a new project to test this behavior in a clean environment.
I added jquery und a small script:

```
var url = "http://thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=The%20Walking%20Dead";
var request = $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
});
```

but i always get:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

and during debugging i can see that the requested url starts with:

```
http://localhost:4400/ripple/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=
```

followed by the url I want.

the config.xml contains:

```
<access origin="http://thetvdb.com" />
<access origin="*" />
```

i also tried to add this before the jquery call:

```
$.support.cors = true;
```

I'm not really sure if the problem is my fault.. but if it is, please tell me ;)

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21742515/3900092). Basically, the ripple cross domain proxy needs to be disabled.

Comment: this was leading to the suggested solutions below ;)

Answer (score 0):

Expand the Settings panel (ripple), Set option for the Cross Origin Proxy = Remote (or Disabled)

Comment: I'm not really sure why, but setting it to "Remote" worked. Setting it to "Disabled" did not..

Comment: It is because your browser (Chrome, FireFox, IE) do not allow xhr to different site. When it was set to Remote, it make xhr to localhost:4400 and ripple check internal that site is remote and setting is allowed this remote request.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying get data from local server - Expand the Settings panel (ripple), Set option for the Cross Origin Proxy = Local and check what proxy port equal opened url (4400 in your case)