# Ripple emulator and VS2015 400 error at login all of a sudden

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, ripple

I'm using the Ripple emulator in Visual Studio 2015 to test and debug a Cordova hybrid app. A few days ago I began to get this error when I try to log into to Office 365 using OAuth:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) xhr_proxy

I've been pulling my hair out trying to get to the root of the issue. The app runs absolutely fine on my laptop without error. It was running find on my desktop until recently. All my other apps also are getting this same error at the same login script and they were working fine last week and weren't touched.

Can anyone shed some knowledge on what might be going on? I'm at a complete standstill until I can figure this out. Thank you.

Comment: Is this a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402422/phonegap-application-not-working-on-google-ripple/21742515#21742515 ?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that post Michael. I've set the cross-domain-policy to all three settings, "local", "remote", and "disabled" but with no luck. I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Never mind. This is just emulator's bug. Use another one. I am using VS2015 emulator. it is working, there is no error.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same error when trying to call an API that i´ve created, and that was hosted on Azure Web Sites.

After search a lot a solution, i´ve discovered that the error was in my code, it was an exception thrown on server, that was returning a 400 HTTP code.